# How to use grep to print specific words only

Tags: shell, jenkins, devops

I have a variable that contains a string-

```
$CCSR = "branches/features/arm_and_musl"
```

I want to pass only the "arm_and_musl" part to a variable, while excluding "branches/features", so something like this-

```
def dirname= sh " echo $CCSR | grep ????? "
```

But the main issue is that I don't want to explicitly mention "arm_and_musl" part, I want it to just exclude "branches/features" and print the remaining part whatever that may be.

I'm not sure what to put here so that only the part I want is passed to the variable.

Could you please suggest any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
echo ${CCSR##*/}
```

to just output the needed section or if you need the variable to contain it use:

```
CCSR=${CCSR##*/}
```

**Edit:**
Since for some reason author was getting an error, thought i would include a solution with `sed`:

```
echo $CCSR | sed "s:.*/::"
```

Comment: This gave me error- WorkflowScript: 50: unexpected char: '#' @ line 50, column 32.

Comment: Added a new solution using sed, but before were done, note this will only work if your desired output has no '/' somewhere in it. If that is not the case please comment and i will add to the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `basename`:

```
#!/bin/sh

CCSR="branches/features/arm_and_musl"
file=$(basename "$CCSR")

echo "$file"
```